# Trying to view User Profile in Django, but Page Not Found when searching URLs

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views, user-profile

I am trying to view a user profile for my website with the Detail CBV. Below is the code for views.py, urls.py, models.py and profile.html.

A user exists with the username "brian_weber", but for some reason when I  navigate to this link: http://0.0.0.0:8000/accounts/profile/brian_weber the page is not found. My app is called "accounts".

If someone could point me in the right direction to get the view to show up with the url, that would be greatly appreciated! I have searched around Stack Overflow, but nothing has worked that I tried.

Thanks in advance,

Brian

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin

from . import forms
from . import models


class LoginView(generic.FormView):
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = "accounts/login.html"

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        if form_class is None:
            form_class = self.get_form_class()
        return form_class(self.request, **self.get_form_kwargs())

    def form_valid(self, form):
        login(self.request, form.get_user())
        return super().form_valid(form)


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))


class SignUp(SuccessMessageMixin, generic.CreateView):
    form_class = forms.UserCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("login")
    template_name = "accounts/signup.html"
    success_message = "Your profile has been successfully created. Please log into your account."


class UserProfile(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = models.UserProfile
    template_name = "profile.html"


class UserProfileUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    model = models.UserProfile
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    url(r'^signup/$', views.SignUp.as_view(), name="signup"),
    url(r'^profile/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$', 
        views.UserProfile.as_view(), 
        name="profile"),
    url(r'^profile/update/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$', 
        views.UserProfileUpdate.as_view(), 
        name="update_profile"),
]
```

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True, default="")
    avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="avatars", 
                                height_field=None, width_field=None)


def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is very small, the regular expression provided in url for profile, `(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)` does not match `brian_weber` because of the `_`.

You can simply update the regex to match `_` too.

```
username_regex = r'[a-zA-Z0-9_]+'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    url(r'^signup/$', views.SignUp.as_view(), name="signup"),
    url(r'^profile/(?P<username>{username})$'.format(username=username_regex), 
        views.UserProfile.as_view(), 
        name="profile"),
    url(r'^profile/update/(?P<username>{username})$'.format(username=username_regex),
        views.UserProfileUpdate.as_view(), 
        name="update_profile"),
]
```

Comment: @e4c5 You have 17k reputation, one less answer won't hurt you :-D

Comment: Thanks MJafar! Now I have another error, this time it's a ValueError. The error is invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'brian_weber'. Do I have to redefine the get_object method? If so, what would the code look like?

Comment: @Brian yes you can do that. Another solution would be setting `slug_field = 'user__username'` although i didn't test it yet, but i guess it works based on this link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object

Comment: I used the slug_url_kwarg = 'username' and slug_field = 'user__username'. Now my view works! Thank you so much :)